# php use all classes with 'use' inside a namespace | not 'include' but 'use <namespace>' | vanilla php

Tags: php

I have a class that uses every single class inside a Controllers folder. To be able to use them i need to do

```
use <namespace>\<class>;
```

But that gets repetitive if you have loads of classes and takes a lot of space.

I know in c# you can include ALL classes inside a specific folder like

```
using Controllers
```

So all the classes will be loaded with the 'Controllers' and wont need to be repeated for 10 times for 10 different classes inside this 'Controllers' namespace.

But how to do that with Php?

I tried looping glob

```
foreach (glob("Controllers/*.php") as $filename) {
   use $filename;
}
```

But throws an error for using 'use' and that is expected since this is a wrong way to use it. Al-tho switching 'use' with 'include' works but then does not find such $filename. I need to use 'use' not 'include'

Is this even possible or am I just wasting time trying to do this without the use of any 3rd party lib or framework (vanilla php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespace in PHP:

let's assume I have

```
App\Namespace1\Foo
App\Namespace1\Bar
App\Namespace2\Baz
```

```
namespace App\Namespace2;

use App\Namespace1;

class Baz
{
  public function __construct(Namespace1\Foo $foo)
  {
    new Namespace1\Bar($foo);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `use` can not be used inside function as of PHP manual

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope)

I think your best bet would be to use PHP7 group use statement

```
use App\Foo{
    Class1,
    Class2,
    Class3
}
```

---

As side note, why you need to use all controllers? Maybe there is some logic that can be separated to different files?

---

Your issue would be solved if all controllers and current class would be under same namespace, then class lookup first checks in current namespace.

---

If you are using dynamic class loading, then you can exclude `use` and call class directly because:

```
use App\Foo\Class1;

...

new Class1();
```

is same as

```
new \App\Foo\Class1();
```

When doing dynamic loading:

```
$className = 'Class1'; // E.g. resolved by some routing
$fullClassName = "\\App\\Foo\\{$className}";
$instance = new $fullClassName();
```

Comment: I have a class 'Route' that depending on a route executes a specific methods in a specific Controller. for example, if the user is inside a index page - executes IndexController::CreateView(), if in page about-us - executes AboutUs::CreateView() and so on.

My controllers are under same namespace. But using "use Controllers" or  "use Controllers\" throws an error for not finding a class "IndexController" class. but if i do "use Controllers\IndexController" it works fine.

Comment: @Lith You can actually drop `use` usage and call classes with full namespace instead. Check my answer' last part

Comment: ah you propobly edited while i was writting a responds, sorry.
Yeah i know you can do that, but im trying to avoid the repeated typing of 'use' or namespace before each class therefore why im trying to minimize the code with 'use' similar how you can do with c# and 'using' but i guess thats not possible in php.

But thanks for your time.

Comment: @Lith Depends on how you load your classes. As I can image, you should be using it one time for any `Controller`, so no repetitive writing

Comment: spl_autoload_register(function($className) 
    {
        include dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . str_replace('\\', "/", $className) . '.php';
    });

Comment: @Lith Autoloader does not need to `use` class, and you already got `$className` with namespace